# Python logging duplicated

Tags: python, logging

I have Four files,

- Main.py
- A.py
- B.py
- Log_System

i am using main to use functions of A.py and B.py, so now i have to log all the information when ever i call them.

so i wrote a script called log_system to create log handler for each script file such as A.py, B.py

```
import logging

def fetchLogger(name="None") :
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    if (name == "None"):
        #create File for Log
        handler = logging.FileHandler('./engine_log/Generic.log')
        handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        #log format 
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        #adding the handler to Logging System
        logger.addHandler(handler)
    else: 
        #create File for Log
        handler = logging.FileHandler('./engine_log/'+str(name))
        handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        #log format 
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        #adding the handler to Logging System
        logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger
```

so if i want to use logging in script file A.py, i would write these line:

```
import log_system 
"""Log System Building """
file_name =  'A.py'
logger = log_system.fetchLogger(file_name)

def hello():
    try:
        logger.info("excuting Hello")
    except: 
        logger.debug("something went wrong in hello")
```

but my log files

```
2017-10-18 14:59:28,695 - log_system - INFO - A.py-excuting Hello
2017-10-18 14:59:28,695 - log_system - INFO - A.py-excuting Hello
2017-10-18 14:59:28,695 - log_system - INFO - A.py-excuting Hello
2017-10-18 14:59:28,695 - log_system - INFO - A.py-excuting Hello
2017-10-18 14:59:28,695 - log_system - INFO - A.py-excuting Hello
```

**it is repeating the log many times.... 
so what should i do ??**

**solution**

```
logger = logging.getLogger(name)

if logger.hasHandlers(): 
    logger.handlers = []

logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#create File for Log
handler = logging.FileHandler('./engine_log/'+str(name))
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
#log format 
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
#adding the handler to Logging System
logger.addHandler(handler)

return logger
```

this is how i changed my log_system code, so i just emptied the Handler list if i had created an log handler already so that it does not create duplicate records.

Comment: i think the most robust method is still just manually duplicating your message both to print statements and logger.info(); explicit is better than implicit

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Every time `fetch_logger` is called it adds a new `FileHandler` to the logger.  Each `FileHandler` writes to the log file, resulting in the repeating output in the file.

One solution is to call the logger's [hasHandlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.hasHandlers) method.  This will return True if any handlers have been configured on the logger, and then you can delete them.

```
def fetchLogger(name="None") :
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    if logger.hasHandlers():
        # Logger is already configured, remove all handlers
        logger.handlers = []
    # Configure the logger as before.
    ...
```

Comment: This is enlightening and finally solved my issue with these duplicate things.
```
if logger.hasHandlers():
        # Logger is already configured, remove all handlers
        logger.handlers = []
```

Appreciate the share and surprised you don't have more upvotes.

Comment: but why such a _hack_ for this? why do we need to always use `logger.hasHandlers`? this seems like a bug in the logging module.

Answer (score 2):

There may be another cause for duplicates when using the `__name__` variable as the logger name.
The logger assumes that dots in the name indicate a parent-child relatationship. If you already created a logger from a module higher in the tree, it is also called to handle the logging.

So if you first `logger = logger.get_logger(__name__)` in module 'foo' and add handlers to it,
then `another_logger = logger.get_logger(__name__)` in module 'foo.bar' and add handlers to it,
you have created a parent and a child.

Using `another_logger.info('Some text')` in the foo.bar module will result in executing the handlers of the 'foo.bar' handler first and then the same message by the 'foo' handler.

Comment: I do not understand. Can you explain better?